# Using different rate than the default 1/second in iptables

Tags: iptables, ddos, syn

This code does its job perfectly in limiting syn connections but in line 4 instead of 1/s i need it to be 1/5 seconds, it's an assignment i'm working on that needs to protect against syn-flood attacks

```
iptables -N syn_flood
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -j syn_flood
iptables -A syn_flood -m limit --limit 1/s --limit-burst 3 -j RETURN
iptables -A syn_flood -j DROP
```

Comment: 1 connection for 5s => 12 connections for 1 minute : --limit 12/min

Answer (score 0):

If you honestly believe that 1 syn per second is "too-much"... you've got some serious server issues.  That being said, The minimum limit for `limit` is 1 second.  Without rewriting that module, you're not going to be able to do less than 1 packet per sec.

Honestly, If you're trying to get 1 packet per 1/5 second... why not simply specify 5/s?  (5 packets per second)  that is pretty much the same thing.

If you're simply trying to limit connections per-host, try using `connlimit` instead of `limit`... or perhaps `hitcount` to limit per-ip connections.

Comment: honestly it's an assignment i'm working on and this is the requirement that's why it's 1/5 seconds. could you help me out with the code to use hitcount or connlimit?

Comment: As this is a very complicated topic, and require a lot of discussion, this isn't really the place to do that.  Also, I am not a fan of doing other people's homework.